# VW Golf 5 JXP and Golf 6 LHY gearbox compatibility

Tags: vw, transmission, golf

I have a VW Golf 6 from 2009, 1.4 TSI, 122 HP, with a problematic LHY gearbox that needs to be replaced. I bought (from a scrap yard) a JXP gearbox from a Golf 5, 1.4 TSI, 140 HP, which they told me is compatible, and they even recommended me a mechanic that can perform the replacement. I also found a few instances on the Web where it did seem that the JXP gearbox may be compatible with my car.

I called a professional service and they didn't know for sure what to say about the compatibilty. They said they have to try, but of course I wouldn't like to pay just for trying... So, is there anyone who can confirm the compatibility?

As a side note, I heard LHY gearboxes are a little bit difficult to come by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final verdict from a professional car service: not compatible.